# How do I limit my date range on an Ajax Calendar?

Tags: c#, java, .net, asp.net, javascript

I am using the ajax calendar tool.  I like its function, but I would like to restrict the user to an option of selecting a time frame starting with Today, and ending with 6 months prior.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the asp.net calendar control, use the DayRender event to check each day against the date limit you wish to impose.

```
protected void Calendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
   //Get date in past relative to current date.
   DateTime dateInPast = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(10));

   if (e.Day.Date < dateInPast || e.Day.Date > DateTime.Now)
      {
         e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
      }
}
```

Comment: Seems like something I should be looking at.  How would I add this to my html page?

Answer (score 0):

Which ajax calendar tool are you using. There are about 7000 out there. I've seen the ones from Yahoo (YUI) and a few others that take configurations for start and end dates where the user has to select something in between.
If you're using a calendar that doesn't have that, you could add it by checking the date after the user selects and checking if that is outside your range. Then display a message and leave the calendar visable for them to pick again. (Might be easier to switch to a calendar that already supports this though)

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp:comaparevalidator to check selected date.